# How to make a VS 2022 VSIX project work in 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

I have an extension made with 2022, but I want it to also work on 2019, how would I go about this?

I changed some version numbers from (17, 18) to (16, 18) like this:

[image: Install Targets]

[image: Prerequisites]

But there is no change, any info helps, thanks.

Edit: I have managed to get it to install using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022), however the wizard doesn't want to work, it says it cannot find the wizard class, I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022) to make the wizard work.

VSIX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
    <Metadata>
        <Identity Id="MelonLoaderModTemplateInstaller.5ff1580f-0e13-48ce-879c-0413b9269ebe" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="korbykob" />
        <DisplayName>MelonLoader Mod</DisplayName>
        <Description xml:space="preserve">A project for making mods with MelonLoader.</Description>
        <Icon>MelonLoaderModTemplate.ico</Icon>
    </Metadata>
    <Installation>
        <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0, 18.0)">
            <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
        <InstallationTarget Version="[17.0,18.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro">
            <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
        <InstallationTarget Version="[17.0,18.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise">
            <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
        <InstallationTarget Version="[16.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community">
            <ProductArchitecture>x86</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
        <InstallationTarget Version="[16.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro">
            <ProductArchitecture>x86</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
        <InstallationTarget Version="[16.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise">
            <ProductArchitecture>x86</ProductArchitecture>
        </InstallationTarget>
    </Installation>
    <Dependencies>
        <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Prerequisites>
        <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[16.0,18.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    </Prerequisites>
    <Assets>
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="MelonLoaderModTemplate" d:TargetPath="|MelonLoaderModTemplate;TemplateProjectOutputGroup|" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:VsixSubPath="ProjectTemplates" />
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" AssemblyName="|%CurrentProject%;AssemblyName|" />
    </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

Comment: Have you seen this page ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022

Comment: No, let me give it a try

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools source - and do not use EnvDTE anywhere.

Comment: It works however, it doesn't like my project wizard, I get an error saying that the wizard class doesn't exist in the assembly, works fine in the debugger.

Comment: Your problem is that the wizard works in visual studio 2022 but not work in visual studio 2019 or something else? Can you provide the code in .vsixmanifest?

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit the post in a moment

Answer (score 0):

I set this in .vsixmanifest file:

[image]

And get this error:

[image]

You can right click on the .vsixmanifest file and choose View Code:

[image]

And then delete `<ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>` in this code:

[image]

For more information you can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/target-previous-versions?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Thanks, but I have managed to get it to install, however the wizard doesn't want to work, sorry I should edit the post...